# Reusing jQuery animate parameters

Tags: jquery, animation

Is there any way to reuse the parameters for the following code? I would like to set `duration: 750,
                easing: 'easeOutBack',
                queue: false` only once instead of on each animation.

```
    $("#box1").hover(function(){
        $("#slide").animate({ left: "0" },{
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'easeOutBack',
            queue: false
         });
        $("#arrow").animate({ left: "-20px" },{
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'easeOutBack',
            queue: false
         });
    });
    $("#box2").hover(function(){
        $("#slide").animate({ left: "-200px" }, {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'easeOutBack',
            queue: false
         });
        $("#arrow").animate({ left: "-40px" },{
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'easeOutBack',
            queue: false
         });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var obj = {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'easeOutBack',
            queue: false
         };

$("#box1").hover(function(){
    $("#slide").animate({ left: "0" }, obj);
    $("#arrow").animate({ left: "-20px" }, obj);
});

$("#box2").hover(function(){
    $("#slide").animate({ left: "-200px" }, obj);
    $("#arrow").animate({ left: "-40px" }, obj);
});
```

Comment: @j08691 - I guess it was my turn !

Comment: Wow you guys are fast! I tried something similar but I guess I had the syntax wrong. Thanks for the quick response! I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var animParams = {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'easeOutBack',
            queue: false
         };

$("#slide").animate({ left: "0" }, animParams);
$("#arrow").animate({ left: "-20px" }, animParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

make an object in a parent function:

```
var mySettings = {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'easeOutBack',
            queue: false
         }
```

Then place that in the animate functions as the second argument

Answer (score 0):

You can clean it up a lot more than that:

```
function animateWithEase($id,$left,$duration,$easing,$queue){
    $id.animate({left:$left},{
        duration:$duration,
        easing:$easing,
        queue:$queue
    });
}

$("#box1").hover(function(){
    animateWithEase($('#slide'),0,750,'easeOutBack',false);
    animateWithEase($('#arrow'),-20,750,'easeOutBack',false);
});
$("#box2").hover(function(){
    animateWithEase($('#slide'),-200,750,'easeOutBack',false);
    animateWithEase($('#arrow'),-40,750,'easeOutBack',false);
});
```

This allows easy modification of the parameters if you want to customize one or more later, and also allows for easy application to other items.

If you wanted to simplify it knowing it won't be customized later::

```
function animateWithEase($id,$left){
    $id.animate({left:$left},{
        duration:750,
        easing:'easeOutBack',
        queue:false
    });
}

$("#box1").hover(function(){
    animateWithEase($('#slide'),0);
    animateWithEase($('#arrow'),-20);
});
$("#box2").hover(function(){
    animateWithEase($('#slide'),-200);
    animateWithEase($('#arrow'),-40);
});
```